# Best practice for automated Linux updates

Tags: linux, yum, puppet, best-practices

We are working on a way to perform automatic updates for our RHEL/RHEL-based servers.

**Initial idea:** Using Puppet, we disable the default repositories and point to our own. Then, we use `ensure => latest` for the packages we want to automatically update.

**Problem:** We are seeing that some services restart after an update (duh).

**Question:** Does anyone have any advice on how to better automate Linux updates and strategies on mitigating the automatic restart of services? We'd prefer a solution that includes Puppet but, if we need to use another service, that is not a deal-breaker.

### Edit

**Possible solution:** I submitted a solution that implements many of what @voretaq7 and @ewwhite suggested. Seems like this is the route I am going for the time being. If you have other suggestions, please comment or submit an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your general update strategy is sound: You have a local repo (which I assume you test in a dev environment), and you update everything based of that (I assume known good) repo.

The service restart thing is inevitable: If the underlying code has changed you need to restart the service for that change to take effect.  Failing to do so can lead to worse consequences (running code out of sync with a shared library leading to a crash of the application).
In my environment I consider the quarterly patch windows to be quarterly "REBOOT ALL THE THINGS!" windows too.  The advantage of such a policy is that you *know* that your servers will come back up after a restart, and you *know* they'll work properly (because you test them regularly).

---

My best advice to you is to schedule the software releases (maybe this means you'll have to trigger them "manually" with puppet), and advise your users of the planned maintenance/downtime.
Alternatively (or as part of this) you can configure redundancy in your environment such that you can have a few machines or services restarting and still provide service to the end users.  This may not completely eliminate any disruptions, but it can help minimize them.

The added redundancy also protects you in the event of hardware failures, which are inevitable on a long-enough time scale.

Comment: +1 for Reboot All The Things.

Comment: @TomO'Connor I've learned the hard way.  I feel very comfortable up to about 3 months between reboots, after that I start wondering what I did that's going to disappear.  Last reboot we actually lost a VPN tunnel (The tunnel was hard-coded & came up, but the route for it wasn't added, so... yeah.)

Comment: Posted a possible solution inspired by you @voretaq7

Comment: @BeamingMel-Bin You should post that as an answer -- it sounds like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thank you. Posted it along with some modifications to the workflow per some thinking I did on the ride home.

Answer (score 5):

Is there necessarily a problem with restarting a service after a package update? Test on a small scale before you deploy to see if there are any issues. I recently had an ugly issue with the rpmforge package of [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/). It actually changed the location of its configuration and work directories between revisions from a yum update. That's totally undesired behavior. Typically, within the same revision of RHEL, there aren't too many issues, but you can never be sure without testing and watching the effects closely.

Another option is to selectively update services. Do you always need the latest packages, for example? This goes back to understanding your reasons for running updates. What is the real goal?

The advantage of running your own repo is that you can stage releases or rollouts and manage the schedule. What if you have a hardware peripheral or software vendor that requires RHEL 5.6 and would break under 5.7? That's one of the benefits to managing your own packages.

Comment: I would say if the update set triggers a service restart you definitely want to do that restart.  Of course if you don't NEED to do that update (it doesn't buy you a feature, security enhancement, or something else you need) I wouldn't do it, or I'd wait until I could schedule the outage to be convenient for myself and my users.

Answer (score 2):

@Beaming Mel-Bin

The simplification will eliminate the need for using ssh for loop tools, to start/stop puppet.

First of all you will need to change your manifests to include a variable called "noop" whose value is sourced from the ENC.

So you would have something like this in a class:

```
noop => $noop_status
```

Where `noop_status` is set in your ENC. When you set the value of `noop_status` to `true`, the manifest will run in noop mode only.

If you have 100s or 1000s of hosts, you can use an ENC like Dashboard or Foreman that lets you mass change parameters for many hosts, by inheriting them at the "Hostgroup" or "Domain" level. You can then set the value to "false" for a small number of test hosts, overriding the Hostgroup value.

With this, any changes get applied to selected hosts only.

*Changing one parameter in a central location can affect any number of hosts, without the need to turn puppet on/off with ssh for loop tools. You can divide your hosts in multiple groups for safety/management.*

Also note that instead of hard coding Package version numbers in manifests, you can put them in the ENC. And just like above, you can selectively apply changes and manage rollouts.

If you want more granularity(and complexity) you can even have per class parameters, like `noop_status_apacheClass` and so on.

This may be harder to manage if you `include` classes in other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution based @voretaq7's answer:

1. Hard code version numbers of packages in the `puppet` manifests and maintain the packages in our own repository.
2. When we require a new version of a package do to something it offers (e.g., security enhancements, features required by our customers, etc.), we download the package to the repository.
3. Test the updated package on a test server.
4. Once update is tested, use something like `func` or `pssh` to shut off `puppet` agent on affected nodes.
5. Update the `puppet` manifests to ensure that the new version of the package is installed on affected nodes.
6. Finally, run `puppet agent --onetime && reboot` on the server using `func` or `pssh`

Please comment and let me know if you spot any deficiencies in this solution or anything that could be simplified.

Comment: It is possible to simplify this using an ENC and parameters. This will require some re-arrangement of the manifests, which may not be possilbe for all.

Comment: Please elaborate @NotNow and post an answer. Intrigued to know.